# what's matter about this message 'isNegative' was called on null Receiver : null

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-listview

**problematic code**

```
Widget Cardlist(Size size, List<Map<String, dynamic>> stocklist ) {

        return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.05),
              itemCount: stocklist.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Stockcard(context, size, stocklist[index]['name'], stocklist[index]['price'],
                    stocklist[index]['perc'], stocklist[index]['volume']);
              },
            ),
        );

}
```

**Stockcard**

```
Widget Stockcard(BuildContext context, Size size, var name, var price, var perc,
    var volume) {
  var color;
  if (perc[0] == '+') {
    color = CHART_PLUS;
  } else {
    color = CHART_MINUS;
  }
  var intl = NumberFormat.currency(locale: "ko_KR", symbol: "￦");

  price = intl.format(price);
  volume = intl.format(volume);

  return Container(
    height: size.height * 0.185,
    width: size.width * 0.9,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(8),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
      ),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.25),
            offset: Offset(0, 4),
            blurRadius: 4)
      ],
      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: size.width * 0.03, vertical: size.height * 0.005),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size.height * 0.03),
    child: Column(
~~~~below code is about design
```

**Widget Build**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: customFuture(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> stockcardlist =  snapshot.data ?? [] ;
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: mainAppBar(
                context,
                "관심 종목",
                SettingButton(context),
              ),
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Cardlist(size, stockcardlist),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**problem**

At first, I thought this problem was caused by the stock card list not being delivered to the stock card list during the build process
After checking using
`print(stocklist.length)`
, the data has been sufficiently transferred.

So I annotated the `return Expanded` statement and checked it using `return Text('text');` and the screen was printed normally. So I was sure that the content of the return expanded plan was a problem.

However, I am suffering because there is no information on NosuchMethodError, isNegative in Internet search.

please help me

Comment: After annotating the return stock card and entering the data with the list with fixed results, the output became normal.

Comment: I don't see `isNegative` used in your code anywhere

Comment: @Pokaboom i find answer just type error thanks

Comment: if you want avoid this dynamic errors then map your json to flutter data class so that it will exactly point where the problem is. Here is online code generator for it https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly, the answer to this was to the `parameter type`. The stocklist contains the int type price, volume, and string type name and perc, but if you put the int type variable as String, the error will occur.